# How to debug all parameters on environments in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I would like to debug my Symfony parameters on specific environments by getting a table with all of them, and their values like:

```
Parameter  | prod  | dev  | foo   |
-----------|-------|------|-------|
appname    | toto  | titi | tata  |
isonline   | true  | true | true  |  // Inheritance appears
firstname  | undef | Bob  | Bob   |  // No values appears
```

Do you know if there is a feature/bundle/command to do that ?

It becomes necessary when you get more than 5 environments with different configurations.

Comment: Are you speaking about config.yml | config_dev.yml | config_prod.yml (etc...) ?

Comment: you can take a look at the standard symfony2 command `app/console container:debug --parameters` in the symfony3 it will be `bin/console debug:container --parameters`

Comment: @scoolnico: Yes, I talk about these files

Comment: @Matteo: It's something ! But I'd like to see them for all environments, so that I can compare them and detect issues before runtime. If nobody did it yet, I will analyse how this command work to make a "parameters report" for all environments

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing that you wish...

Comment: you can pass the env to this command `--env=test` or `--env=foo` if you find some bundle that does this work let me know!

Comment: Using this command and aggregating returns, we can make a summary of the parameters quite easily ! I will try this, stay tuned !

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As @Matteo said in comment, you could use the command below to see all your parameters

```
php bin/console debug:container --parameters --env=prod
```

But there is not any command to list all your parameters from all your environments, you have to make a script (bash script with grep and the command above) or a Symfony command to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 18):

Regardless of how you set environment variables, you can see a full list with their values by running:

```
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars
```

See [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#listing-environment-variables) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Although the OP asks about parameters and not environment variables, I'll add this answer because someone who is searching may find this command, new in Symfony 5.4/6, helpful:

bin/console debug:dotenv