# How to check the environment using the Symfony console tool?

Tags: symfony, environment, symfony-console

I use the Symfony CLI tool, and I'm looking for a way to check the environment. I could not find anything like

```
$ php bin/console get environment
```

Is there another way for that? Is it possible / How to find out, which environment is currently active?

---

The application is running in a concrete environment (and using then the `app.php` for `prod` or an `app_{env}` for any other environment).

So what I actually want to achieve is to find out, which environment is currently being used by the application (when the app is called via HTTP, e.g. in a browser).

Answer (score 55):

```
php bin/console about
```

This will display info about your app, one row will  concern Environment:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about this one... I've been on SF for over a year now, what the hell.

Answer (score 33):

```
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars
```

Comment: this solution is better than first one. for example it saw `DATABASE_URL` which wasn't visible with `php bin/console about`.

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.environment');
```

in ContainerAwareCommand?

Comment: `ContainerAwareCommand` has been deprecated in 4.2 and should be used anymore, so this solution shouldn't be used.

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-important-deprecations#deprecated-containerawarecommand

Comment: You can use `ParameterBagInterface` injected as a dependency instead.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question has been asked a long time ago, but if it could be useful for womeone, in Sf5.4 (at least, maybe Sf6+ too), you could use

```
php bin/console debug:dotenv
```

to have all the variables set by .env files (and so, the APP_ENV too)

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395792/how-to-debug-all-parameters-on-environments-in-symfony

Answer (score 4):

As for Symfony that uses Flex you can get APP_ENV variable via getenv() PHP function:

```
getenv('APP_ENV');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just typing in:

```
php bin/console
```

will show you all the commands available. I think normally by default, both 'dev' and 'prod' are available. You can specify commands specific to an environment by using the option `--env=ENV`.

So to debug the routing in `dev` you would enter:

```
php bin/console --env=dev debug:router
```

and it would show routes in the `dev` environment. I'm not sure if that helps you or not.

---

**EDIT #2**

You could add a test to you Twig file and print out your environment:

```
<p>Application Environment: {{ app.environment }}</p>
```

This is a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! But I mean something else: The application is running in a concrete environment (and using then the `app.php` for `prod` or an `app_{env}` for any other environment). So how to find out, which environment is currently be use by the application, when (when the app is called via a HTTP request, e.g. in a browser)?

Comment: You should probably update your post with that particular info.

Comment: I added an EDIT #2 section - take a look to see if that helps or not.

Answer (score -1):

When you can't get the container injected in any way, as a last resort you can try

```
 $environment = $GLOBALS["env"];
```